# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que dos botones ocupen todo un espacio como si se usara btn-block?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo el sigiuente código, lo que quiero, es que los dos botones de cada columna en la segunda fila ocupen el 100% del espacio de la clase .col como pasa en la primera fila con la clase btn-block, ¿cómo podría hacerlo?

```css
*{
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">
  
    <div class="col">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-dark">Column 1 - Row 1</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-dark">Column 2 - Row 1</button>
    </div>
    
  </div>

  <br />

  <div class="row">
  
    <div class="col">
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-block" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">356a</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Column 1 - Row 2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">356a</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Column 2 - Row 2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución a temas de diseño es más de CSS, puedes añadir algunas clases y controlar el ancho de las filas. Por ejemplo:

```css
*{
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}
.btn-group .btn {
  width: 50%;
}
.btn-group {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">
  
    <div class="col">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-dark">Column 1 - Row 1</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-dark">Column 2 - Row 1</button>
    </div>
    
  </div>

  <br />

  <div class="row">
  
    <div class="col">
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-block" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">356a</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Column 1 - Row 2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">356a</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Column 2 - Row 2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```